# Spring Data Couchbase Connecting via SSL

Tags: ssl, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Is it possible to configure spring-data-couchbase to connect via SSL?

I have found [documentation for how to do this via the SDK](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/managing-connections.html#ssl), but not in [spring-data-couchbase 3.1.4-RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.configuration)

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to do this is to extend `AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration` with your own configuration, and then Override the methods in that class with the SSL config as per the SDK documentation.  For example:

```
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

  @Override
  public CouchbaseEnvironment couchbaseEnvironment() {
    return DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment
        .builder()
        .sslEnabled(true)
        .sslKeystoreFile("/path/tokeystore")
        .sslKeystorePassword("password")
        .build();
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you may be correct @robjwilkins. I'm having difficulty getting an example to work locally but I suspect the problem is at the SDK level and not `spring-data-couchbase`. Once I have a fully working proof of concept I'll happily accept your answer, and provide a link to the full source code.